How add stop words in a language not listed in prerocess text filtering in Orange?
In Orange Preprocess Text window, in the Filtering section, the Stopwords are provided in a list of languages. We can also load our own list of stopwords. Is it also possible to load our own list of stopwords in a language not listed in this section? For example, can we load a list of stopwords in Persian? Will orange still apply it properly in preprocessing?

Yes it should work as long as each stop word is created in its own line. Since Orange applies stopword removal based solely on the words in the file, it does not need to understand the language specifically. So, as long as the file is loaded correctly, it will filter out any matching words in your Persian text data during preprocessing.
Therefore, create a file persian_stopwords.txt and load that in the preprocess text widget filtering section and it will pick up the stop words. Hope this helps.
